# Fontawesome F18C ( fa-pagelines) symbol is not shown but most of the others working good

Tags: font-awesome

I have a website, which uses the icon font FontAwesome:
[amorra.co](http://amorra.co)

In the middle of the homepage there should be the sign with the codepoint [F18C (fa-pagelines) of the FontAwesome font](http://fontawesome.io/icon/pagelines/), though it's not there:

Why is the F18C codepoint not shown?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The simple answer is that your version of the FontAwesome font does not have a symbol for the Unicode codepoint F18C.

To demonstrate that I opened the font in [FontCreator](http://www.high-logic.com/font-editor/fontcreator.html):

[image: F18C codepoint of FontAwesome in FontCreator]

So you should [update to the latest version](http://fontawesome.io/) of that font or choose another codepoint.

Comment: I did so. But the problem still there. Please help me (((

Comment: I updated everywhere for the last version bu the problem still there (

Comment: I fixed the problem. Thank you! I did not know that uikit also using fontawesome library...

Comment: In your question you should have mentioned that you are using the uikit framework. Anyway, if my answer helped you, you should upvote or accept it.